# Streets and Intersections Data Structure

Tags: c++, database, data-structures, language-agnostic

I am writing a program that is supposed to emulate a city, and one of the problems I am running into is how to store a large amount of interconnected data. For instance, each `Street` has a `direction` enumeration (NORTH_ONE_WAY, EAST_WEST, etc.) and other attributes. The most important attribute is that each street has a list of `intersections` (a map of the street that it intersects with along with the block number at which it intersects). From this data structure, I should be able to parse it and create a visualization (that comes later and is not part of this question).

The question is: what is the best type of data structure to use for this? Obviously a relational database would be a good choice, but if I am writing in C++ (not a constraint for this question, but C++ implementation would be a plus), should I be using that? What other data structures may work for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure you describe is a *graph*. See, e.g., [Boost's](http://www.boost.org/) [BGL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) for a generic library operating on graphs. Note, that this doesn't mean you won't use a database: the storage of data and the in-memory representation tend to be rather different. The actual representation tends to depend on what you want to do with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not maintain relations in each local object. Have a 'meta' object evaluating the relation, it may cache these.

Some elaboration:
A street should know it lanterns and nice gardens and the intersections, of course. But it is an intersection to whatever (it does not matter). The street might have a single lane or a a double lane at the intersection (for left turns). The intersection is maintained by some higher instance.

(An apology to left lane drivers)

Comment: You mean Main St should not store the intersection with Fairfield, and Fairfield should not store the intersection with Main...there should be a separate object altogether to store that single intersection (and the others)?